# For a package foo, how do I find out what other packages depend on foo?

Tags: debian, package-management

In debian if I have an installed package foo. How can I get a list of all the packages that depend on foo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apt-cache rdepends <foo>` can do this:

```
$ apt-cache rdepends apt-listchanges
apt-listchanges
Reverse Depends:
  cyrus-common-2.2
  education-common
  cyrus-common-2.2
  apticron
  amavisd-new
```